# Possible virus, windows freezes on login

Tags: windows, virus

my laptop keeps jamming up. I ran "hijackthis" and deleted the relevant files (3 keep reappearing, those system32 files that aren't actually in the system 32 folder (as you guys know, red flags)

I ran the kasperty antivirus, came up with nothing. This was a week ago

now it jams up almost immediately after I log into my desktop (under any user). The only way I keep it from immediately jamming is by using safe mode. Even then, it still jams up after a while. I've been trying to run kasperty full computer scan, but it always jams up at 87% on a file called "\amd64_microsoft-windows-kernel32.resour" (the full file name doesn't show up during a scan, just a fragment of it)

I'm wondering if it may be a hardware problem such as if it overheated at some point and caused motherboard damage.

[image]

the checked one keeps coming back. do I "fix" the other ones that say "its probably nasty" but rated safe?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause (but not only) in a laptop randomly freezing is due to hard drive failure or motherboard failure.

If you have a Windows Vista or 7 disk, use it and click repair, then go to the command prompt and type the following:

```
chkdsk c: /f
```

see if it comes back with any errors. If it does, I advise changing your Hard drive ASAP, If it doesn't, you probably have something else wrong which is usually component on the motherboard failing and there is no easy fix.

For your information, heat related problems usually cause the machine to immediately power down before anything critical can occur and not freeze.

Answer (score 1):

As Wil has already covered hardware, I'll concentrate on software:

I haven't seen any red flags in your image, and I would suggest against using hijackthis, as unless you know exactly what you're doing, it's easy enough to destroy your Windows installation with one click.

If your computer keeps on freezing, you may use a rescue live-CD virus scanner such as [Avira AntiVir Rescue System](http://www.free-av.com/en/tools/12/avira%5Fantivir%5Frescue%5Fsystem.html) (updated several times a day and so the download CD is up-to-date). As a boot CD it doesn't need Windows to be functioning.

If this doesn't find anything, I suggest that you try to rollback Windows to a system restore point dating from before you used hijackthis, and avoid using this utility in the future.

If you have no such system restore point, you might need to do a repair installation of Windows. However, better check first all other possible remedies.

Comment: Are you recommending not using Hijack This? Just curious, why?

Comment: Hijack generates an enormous list where normally all items are legal and correct, but everything can easily be deleted. I've seen cases where a non-professional had in this way destroyed the OS and required re-installation. That's why I truly believe it's too dangerous for end-users.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to a Live CD is pulling your hard drive, and using a IDE/SATA to USB converter to attach it to a clean system and use that system's A/V to deworm your hard drive.